# SwiftUI TabView indexDisplayMode issue

Tags: swiftui, tabview

[image]

I wanna hide TabView indicator but when I set `indexDisplayMode: .never` but I can't see Views under TabView.

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
                        ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                            OnboardingItemView()
                                .tag(index)
                                .readSize { size in
                                    self.size = size
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: size.height)
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: selection)
                    .transition(.slide)
                    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
```

Comment: Have you tried setting indexDisplayMode to .automatic?

Comment: I tried but same